# How can I remove a plastic cupholder glued to the wood frame of a large mirror? I don't want to damage the frame or mirror

Tags: mounting, adhesive, removal

How can I remove a plastic cupholder glued to the wood frame of a large mirror?The mirror is on our bathroom wall above the sink. I don't want to damage the frame or mirror. The cupholder is stuck on quite tightly and there does not appear to be any nails involved. Please Help!

Comment: Glued with what?

Comment: If double sided tape or silicon dental floss may cut it loose but we need to know the type of adhesive.

Comment: Please provide some additional information regarding this cup holder, possibly including a nice clear closeup picture of the holder attachment to the frame. Your question is in danger of being closed without this additional info. As such you will likely not get too much in the way of answers of removal suggestions without it.

Answer (score 1):

Get a 3" wide plastic drywall knife and cut off the handle. Wrap masking tape around the cut end, and you can use it like a saw. A second plastic drywall knife 1" wide can be used to pry away the cupholder as you cut.
After the cupholder is gone use the "saw" to cut away the glue, just like slicing bread. If the wood is painted you can remove the glue and repaint. If the wood is plastic coated you could test a solvent like alcohol or artist thinners. If the wood is varnished, look for a goo-gone product safe for varnish. Coconut oil dissolves many things, but test it first on a hidden edge.